# Compute the maximum element of an 2D-array when the maximums elements of each row and column are given to you, in O(logn)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have 2-dimensional array with size `n x n`. The maximums elements of each row and column are given. For example, if n = 4:

```
int[][] arr = {{2, 3, 10, 1} 
               {9, 2, 8, 12},
               {5, 18, 2, 10},
               {7, 9, 3, 5}}
```

I also have the maximums of each row which are 10, 12, 18, 9 and the maximums of each column which are 9, 18, 10, 12. So I want to find the maximum element of entire array, which is 18, in `O(logn)`. 
Is there any algorithm for this problem ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm missing something, but wouldn't finding the max from either the row or column maxima just be an `O(n)` operation?  Or are you asking about something else?

Comment: These maximums are given. So you don't have to compute them. In other words, you have 8 elements (maximums) which are the above and you have to find the maximum of these.

Comment: I answered as best I could below - if you have any extra information to give me about the list of maximums, perhaps I can improve the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum element in the array is by default the maximum of both its row and its column. We know that either list will not contain a larger number, since it is the maximum element - so it will be the largest in both lists.

Therefore, we just need to find the largest in the list of row maximums (or the column maximums, you do not need both).

You can find the maximum in `O(n)` if the maximum list is unsorted, or `O(1)` if it is sorted. I cannot imagine any way the maximum element can be found in `O(logn)` without more data.

If you consider **n** in the time complexity as the number of elements in the array and not the number of a single side, you get a bit closer - we can have the solution in O(sqrt(n)) - but not O(logn).

Comment: I agree with this, and assuming the 1D array of maxima is completely unsorted, I think the best we could do would be to mergesort it which costs `O(N*lgN)`.

Comment: We only need the maximum of row maximums - so one go on all the row maximums - and we have the max element in hand by simply doing up to n exchanges.

Comment: The time complexity is a function of basic operations and data input. In this case we have nxn elements. So if we calculate this for the above array (n=4, n^n=16), it will be log16 = log(2^4)= 4log2=4 comparisons. Am I right ?

Comment: That is true for 4x4, because log(16) = 4. But if you had 6X6, log(36) is 5.17 - not 6. and for 10X10 you will get log(100) = 6.64, whereas you will need 10 to get the maximum.

Comment: By the way, @DimitrisMpl, if you find my answer above helpful, would you consider accepting it? Just click on the grey check mark next to it, making it green.

Answer (score 1):

The 4*4 example given shows that the row/column maxima are unsorted (and follow the original row/column ordering). So all n row maxima (or column maxima, if you prefer using them) have to be inspected, taking n steps. Less than n, and you might skip the real maximum.

So it can be done in O(n) and nothing less.